# clojurescript could not locate cljs.core.async.macros

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, core.async

I have the following code in the file client.cljs :

```
(ns onn.client
    (:require [enfocus.core :as ef]
          [enfocus.effects :as effects]
          [enfocus.events :as events]
          [clojure.browser.repl :as repl]
          [goog.net.XhrIo :as xhr]
          [cljs.core.async :as async :refer [chan close!]])
    (:use-macros [enfocus.macros :only [deftemplate defsnippet defaction]])
    (:require-macros [cljs.core.async.macros :refer [go alt!]]
))
;....the actual code follows
```

The project file looks like this:

```
(defproject onn "DEV-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write this!"
  :url "http://exampl.com/FIXME"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
             [ring/ring-core "1.1.8"]
             [ring/ring-jetty-adapter "1.1.8"]
             [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-1820"]
             [org.clojure/core.async "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"]
             [enfocus "2.0.0-SNAPSHOT"]]
  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "0.3.2"]
            [lein-ring "0.8.3"]]
  :cljsbuild {:builds [{:source-paths ["src"],
                    :compiler {:pretty-print true,
                               :output-to "resources/public/js/main.js",
                               :warnings true,
                               :optimizations :whitespace}}]}
  :ring {:handler onn.server/app :port 3000})
```

...when compiled gives me this error:

```
Caused by: clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: 
Could not locate cljs/core/async/macros__init.class or cljs/core/async/macros.clj 
on classpath:  at line 1 src/onn/client.cljs
```

Note that my code is copied from here: https://github.com/Dimagog/AsyncGET/blob/master/cljs/app.cljs This guy's project has the same dependencies and it works.

Any idea why? Thanks!

UPDATE:
My cljsbuild was on auto. After restarting cljsbuild it compiles just fine. Thanks!

Comment: Did you restart `lein cljsbuild` after modifying project.clj?

Comment: I didn't. My cljsbuild was on auto! After restarting cljsbuild it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cljsbuild was on auto. After restarting cljsbuild it compiled just fine

Answer (score 6):

I got this error when I was (mistakenly) using `:include-macros true` in my require for `cljs.core.async`:

```
;; THROWS ERROR
(ns my-ns
  (:require [cljs.core.async :refer [<!] :include-macros true])
  (:require-macros [cljs.core.async.macros :refer [go]]))
```

Removing it worked:

```
;; DOES NOT THROW ERROR
(ns my-ns
  (:require [cljs.core.async :refer [<!]])
  (:require-macros [cljs.core.async.macros :refer [go]]))
```

Comment: FYI, this is because the macros moved to `cljs.core.async.macros`.

Answer (score 3):

Your `project.clj` file looks to be missing the repository that the [AsyncGET](https://github.com/Dimagog/AsyncGET) project used.

```
:repositories { "sonatype-oss-public" "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/" }
```

Comment: ...or use the proper Maven release  [org.clojure/core.async "0.1.242.0-44b1e3-alpha"] - but this is the way to go if you want the bleeding edge of core.async

Comment: Generally true, except he based his code on another project that used the SNAPSHOT version. In this case, it's better to get the code working first, before switching to a "proper Maven release".

Comment: Clearly true - this is why I haven't answered on my own, I just wanted to notice that. In general it's not really good practice to use SNAPSHOT releases because they will automatically be updated and thus mess with your version control. E. g. an earlier commit may be unusable because it was working only with an earlier snapshot.

Comment: It worked the same even if I add the :repositories. It seems the cljsbuild had to be restarted. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have ran into this also. Running `lein cljsbuild clean` enabled cljsbuild to pull in the library and build successfully.

Comment: Something like this fixes it. As you can see the UPDATE section, the build was the problem. I was running a long lived "lein cljsbuild auto" in the background. Once I restarted the cljsbuild everything was normal.

Answer (score 0):

Only if your error is related with the brepl ...

If you are trying to use this code into the "standard" clojurescript brepl, first you need to evaluate the clojure macros code into the repl, and then the async macros will be available from the brepl. Also, You can try for interactive coding on the brepl the @cemerick/austin tool https://github.com/cemerick/austin